# Why did changing from Jquery 1.5.1 to Jquery 1.8.1 break all of my CSS in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modernizr

I'm not quite sure what happened. I replaced jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate (**not** jquery.validate.unobtrusive), and modernizr. I updated the files to: 1.8.1, 1.8.23, 1.8.1, and 2.6.2, respectively. I've updated the _Layout.cshtml file to reflect the changes as well. And the CSS broke.  So then, I replaced the CSS and Images in the Content folder and replaced them with the new JQuery UI stuff. Still broken. When I say broken I mean the gray background of the body is gone. The whole page color is blue. Except the tabs (those background color is still gray). Also, my divs no longer float to the left. They just render one under the other.

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I would recommend posting a screenshot of the /Content and /Scripts directory structure, as well as the relevant section of your layout.cshtml

Comment: do u have any console errors/any 404s?

Comment: @InternalServerError: No, it builds just fine and I'm not getting errors of that sort. Actually I'm not getting any errors at all.

Comment: Use your browser's DOM inspector to see how the styles cascade, and find out which ones are overriding which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the script that Modernizr generated started like this: `;window.Modernizr = function (a, b, c)`. Once I removed the `;`, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason upgrading jQuery should affect your CSS.  jQuery has nothing to do with CSS, other than having some style sheets that are specific to jQuery UI.

More than likely, you have made a mistake when you updated your html to use the new jQuery, and the HTML is no longer valid.  You might want to show the html code from your layout.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery 1.8 requires this on top of your main document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

If you built your page with that from the start, all functionalities should work fine, but if you add it after you wrote your page, then it will probably mess up your page too.

Comment: ...Really? I would think that requirement would not hold to JQuery 1.9 or 2.0 because of HTML5.